# Sync local offline domain and Azure

Tags: active-directory, azure

our organization uses an old domain name for the intranet (let's call it corp.com), which differs from the website and email domain (let's call that company.com). Please note that corp.com is NOT registered on the internet as a public domain.

**the goal**
We started to migrate the e-mail services from the internal services to Outlook on Office365, with cloud-based exchange. The first users in Azure were created from scratch, but I would like to mirror the whole AD tree to Azure, without duplicates.

**how far I got**
I added company.com as an alternative UPN suffix to the local AD, and prepped the forest to be used with AD Connect.
**Since corp.com is not registered, I cannot add it into Azure and verify it!** (..right?)

The program asks me to "select the on-premises attribute to use as the Azure AD username". Now, the UserPrincipalName in the corp.com AD, would be user@corp.com, but:
1. that wouldn't match the existing users created from scratch into Azure
2. we would like the users to log into both their windows account just by using "user" (without specifying the domain) and for the single-sign-on onto 365 to work transparently.

Even if I used the email address (user@company.com) as a username (which would match the Azure usernames), I would still be faced with the problem that
**"Users will not be able to sign-in to Azure AD with on-premises credentials if the UPN suffix does not match a verified domain"** - which corp.com is not.

**the question**
Are these our only options or is there a way out?
- buy a domain name for corp.com, which is not possible because it is already owned
- rename corp.com into intranet.company.com, but I can't even begin to imagine the pain..
- forget about syncing Azure

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. You created the UPN Suffix for company.com in AD, so set that as the UPN Suffix on your AD user accounts. The AD UPN Suffix for all of your users will then match the verified domain in Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added company.com as an alternative UPN suffix to the local AD, and
>   prepped the forest to be used with AD Connect. Since corp.com is not
>   registered, I cannot add it into Azure and verify it! (..right?)

You already add the registration company.com to your local AD, after syncing to Azure, your users could sign in Azure AD with the UPN suffix of corp.com, so you not need to buy or rename corp.com.